# cpp undefined reference to `class::method'

Tags: c++, gcc

When I try to compile

$ gcc -lcurl try.cpp

```
/tmp/ccJs0k9m.o: In function `main':
try.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `getURL::fetch(char*, char*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The method appears in the header and the class body. What is wrong exactly?

try.cpp

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include "getURL.h"

int main(void) {

getURL my_getURL;

my_getURL.fetch("http://stackoverflow.com/", "file");
}
```

getURL.h

```
#ifndef _getURL
#define _getURL

class getURL {
public:
    void fetch(char *url, char *filename);
};
#endif
```

getURL.cpp

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <stdio.h>


class getURL {

private CURL *curl;

public getURL() {
    //code
}

public void fetch(char *url, char *filename) {
    //code
}

private size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    //code
}

public ~getURL() {
    //code
}

} //end class
```

Comment: `$ gcc try.cpp getURL.cpp -lcurl`

Comment: @jrok: Libraries have to come at the end of the line.

Comment: @KerrekSB a fact that has caused me much headache.

Comment: How does `getURL.cpp` even compile? Doesn't look like C++. Where are the colons after the access specifiers? Semicolon after the class definition? And if it could somehow be convinced to compile, then `getURL.cpp` and `try.cpp` have completely different ideas about what a getURL object looks like. [edit: ninja'd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only compiling one of your source files.

Change:

```
gcc -lcurl try.cpp
```

to:

```
gcc -lcurl try.cpp getURL.cpp
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the correct implementation syntax; it's

```
getURL::getURL() {
    //code
}

void getURL::fetch(char *url, char *filename) {
    //code
}

size_t getURL::write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    //code
}

getURL::~getURL() {
    //code
}
```

Note that you must not repeat the `class` part in the implementation (just include the header instead). Note also that you're not allowed to have private members in the implementation that are not visible in the declaration... this is unfortunate but it's how the language is defined.

Comment: They also need to lose a lot of "`public`" and "`private`" in the function definitions.

Comment: I added getURL:: to the start of the method names, removed public and private before them. I added the private method to the header file (why?). And removed class {} from getURL.cpp. I think that sums up what you said.

Exact same error.

Comment: Also to compile a C++ program you need to call `g++`, not `gcc`.